# ISP Throttles Internet on HTTP, HTTPS works fine (OpenVPN and Proxy also get throttled)

Tags: vpn, proxy, openvpn, squid, throttling

I want to setup OpenVPN on my server but I have very weird problem which I just noticed while setting it up. I think my ISP is throttling speed over HTTP connections.

**Without VPN and Without Proxy (Direct Internet)**

- I created one HTTP server, placed one 100mb file
- Downloaded that file over IP address. Speed is just 30-40 KB/s
- Downloaded that file over HTTP. Speed is again just 30-40 KB/s
- Downloaded that file over HTTPS. Speed is very fast as my normal internet connection. Even the SSL certificate was self-signed.
- The issue is not my custom server. Whatever file I download over internet if it's HTTP connection then speed is limited.

**With VPN (OpenVPN)**

- All the downloads, whether it's over HTTP or HTTPS, the speed is limited to 30-40 KB/s
- I also tested with 443 TCP port for OpenVPN client. But still same result.
- I also tested with OpenVPN XOR scramble patch.

**With Proxy (Squid3)**

- All the downloads, whether it's over HTTP or HTTPS, the speed is limited to 30-40 KB/s.
- I used explicit proxy not transparent.
- I also tested with 443 TCP port for Squid. But still same result.

As you can see, when I use OpenVPN or Squid3 then my speed is limited either I download files over HTTP or HTTPS.

Is there any solution to this problem so that I can use OpenVPN or Squid3 with good internet speed?

Comment: Try setting up `stunnel` between you and your server and see if that's throttled.  If it isn't, then use OpenVPN over that or other lightweight tunnelling.

Comment: Using stunnel, proxy server now works fine. Thanks for your help. But for OpenVPN, the speed only moved from 30 to 60 KB/s which is still very low. I also needed to add `route {ip} 255.255.255.255 net_gateway` to my OpenVPN client config. I don't think there is any configuration problem as my ISP throttling only works till afternoon. In evening and night with same configuration, speed with OpenVPN or Proxy is very fast.

Comment: Make sure OpenVPN is in UDP mode over stunnel (tcp over tcp is bad).  If you are only using OpenVPN for these two endpoints, try also disabling encryption (since stunnel handles that).

Comment: OpenVPN over UDP with stunnel is not supported. As stunnel only transfer's to TCP protocol. I think stunnel with proxy server is enough for me for now. You can write answer on this question and I will mark as correct. Thanks  very much for your help.

Comment: I again tested with OpenVPN over stunnel and this time it is working very good. Speed is now very high as without VPN. So we can say that my problem is solved by using stunnel and tunnel both VPN and Proxy over it. Thanks.